# ant android change path to build.xml

Tags: android, ant

i am new to android and ant, i created an android app that i'd like to build using ant.
I did an `android update project --path .` which worked like a charm.
Now i want to move the `~/projects/myandroidapp/build.xml` to `~/projects/build_my_app.xml`
When i run ant on this file i receive `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/user/projects/AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory)`
I manipulated every reference to AndroidManifest.xml in former build.xml and main_rules.xml i found but did not find a solution.

Maybe there is someone out there who already faced this problem.

Comment: "Now i want to move the ~/projects/myandroidapp/build.xml to ~/projects/build_my_app.xml" -- why?

Comment: @CommonsWare: To include it into a bigger project which has a 'global' build.xml that builds android project and other projects as well. I thought it would be nice to copy the build chain from the generated build script to save some time.

Answer (score 1):

Try mentioning the `basedir` attribute in your `<project>` tag.

E.g. your build.xml could look like this:

```
<project name="MyProject" basedir="myandroidapp/">
...
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than include the android build script inside the global build file, you could call the ant task of the android build from the global build.

```
<ant antfile="myandroidapp/build.xml" target="mytarget"/>
```

This will segregate the builds of each subproject and simplify the main build file.